# Google Analytics Reporting API - ga:mobileDeviceInfo dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to obtain session data from the Google Analytics API (v3), however am getting some very strange results.

If I use the ga:sessions measure and ga:dateHourMinute dimension; I am able to obtain correct results.

However - if I add ga:mobileDeviceInfo as another dimension to the query, I receive a reduced dataset (based upon total of ga:sessions)

Is anyone able to assist?

Comment: Note: The results of both queries do not contain sampled data.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that non-mobile devices (rather than populating ga:mobileDeviceInfo as null) will be excluded from the results when including this dimension. This does not appear in the documentation.